# How are Materia created?

Tags: final-fantasy

In the universe of Final Fantasy 7, humans seem not to be able to use magic, so they created Materias. In game, Materias contain spells, abilities or power-ups. I guess in lore they don't really contain abilities, it sounds weird to be able to i.e. paint something without learning how to paint but only holding a "Paint" Materia.

So, how are these Materias created?
What is the raw material, and how do you manage to make your Materia effective?

What about espers? In FF7R, Chadley creates Materias - including summons - using data the player collects. But can he create the same "Shiva" Materia multiple times?

Comment: I am not sure if this can be answered for the whole Final Fantasy franchise at once, because each game takes place in its own universe and the rules of these universes tend to differ quite a lot. Are you asking about FF7 in particular?

Comment: Oh yes absolutely. But I guess Materias only exist in FF7?

Comment: Materia also exists [in some other games](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Materia_(term)) in some form or another. Most are games which take place in the FF7 universe, but it also plays a prominent role in the unconnected FF 14 universe and appear in a very minor role in Final Fantasy Tactics.

Comment: Oh i didn't know, thanks for sharing!

Comment: I have this vague memory of Materia being explained as crystallized magic, but I have no idea where I got that from, or if it's canon.

Comment: Ah, https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Materia_(Final_Fantasy_VII), which still doesn't explain how humans do the crystalization process, which also happens naturally.

Comment: Shinra exclusive industrial process.

Comment: Well, at least now I know that Mako naturally crystallizes into Materias. Maybe Shinra's scientists just speed it up, since they extract Mako.

Comment: If this is about materia in FF7 in particular consider adding the relevant tag to the question.

Comment: Hello IG_42, I already considered that at first, but the "ff7" tag doesn't exist, and I can't create it. But I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In Final Fantasy 7, Materia are crystallized from the Lifestream. Materia can be formed naturally, although this is rare due to the conditions and time required. Examples of natural Materia include the White and Black Materia central to the main quest and the Materia found during the Materia Caves sidequests.

Mako reactors can be used to create Materia, as evidenced by the dialog between Scarlet and Tseng at Gongaga:

> Scarlet: ......Hmph! This isn't any good either.
> You only get junky materia from junky reactors. This reactor's a failure. What I'm looking for is big, large, huge materia. You seen any?
>
> Tseng: ...No I haven't seen it. I'll get on it right away.
>
> Scarlet: Please. We could make the ultimate weapon if we only had some.

In Crisis Core, the process for refining natural Mako is explained by NPCs in the Materia Room at the Shinra Building:

> Materia is the concentrated essence of mako energy. But natural materia is practically nonexistent. That's because special conditions must be met, in addition to the long years it takes to form. Most of the materia out there was generated by either us or the Arms Development Department.
>
> Naturally-formed materia are extremely rare, but "mako stones" are relatively easy to obtain. A mako stone is crystallized materia made of concentrated mako energy. By itself, it doesn't have the same effect as materia, but we can process it into materia. SOLDIER members occasionally go out excavating for them. [. . .] If you bring your mako stone in, we can make it into materia for you.